# Java can not find my class

Tags: java, class

```
import java.lang.Exception;

public class ClassroomTester {
    public static void main (String [] agrs)// throws Exception
    {
        Classroom class = new Classroom(5, "CS102");    

    }
}
```

This is the tester class of a Classroom class , but JCreator neither highligths the "Classroom" nor gives an error/exception about not being able to find it. It gives syntax errors such :

error: not a statement ,
error: ';' expected , error:  expected , error: illegal start of type , error: reached end of file while parsing.

The assignment is about throwing exceptions (FileNotFoundException , IOException etc.) and we were supposed to edit the classes (Mostly Classroom ) and test it.

Comment: Post your `Classroom` class

Comment: If the `Classroom` class and the `ClassroomTester` class are not in the same package, you have to import the `Classroom` class. Further, you don't have to import anything in `java.lang`.

Comment: `class` is very probably a reserved java keyword .

Comment: Exactly , i just couldn't see a basic problem that "class" is reserved .. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simple. You can't use "class" as the variable name. It is a reserved keyword. Please change the variable name to some other valid name.

```
   Classroom classRoom = new Classroom(5, "CS102");
```